# Pyspark es.query only works when default

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, elasticsearch, pyspark

In pypspark the only way I can get data returned from ES is by leaving es.query default. Why is this?

```
es_query = {"match" : {"key" : "value"}}
es_conf = {"es.nodes" : "localhost", "es.resource" : "index/type", "es.query" : json.dumps(es_query)}
rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(inputFormatClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsInputFormat",keyClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable",valueClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable", conf=es_conf)
...
rdd.count()
0
rdd.first()
ValueError: RDD is empty
```

Yet this query (the default) seems to work

```
es_query = {"match_all" : {}}
...
rdd.first()
(u'2017-01-01 23:59:59)
```

*I have tested the queries by directly querying elastic search and they work so it is something wrong with spark/es-hadoop.

Comment: Juist to confirm, you are using the same commands in between the query definition and the `rdd.first()` call, correct?

Comment: Yes, everything besides es_query remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

By default the API adds "query":{} in front of your actual query.
For the elasticsearch the query you are sending will look like

```
"query" :{
"match" : {"key" : "value"}
}
```

which is not valid.